# In scala, how to appoint generics to extend case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I write a trait likes this:

```
trait Extractor[T] {

    def parse(sc: SparkContext, path: String): RDD[T]

    def extract(sc: SparkContext, path: String, output: String): Unit = {
        val rdd = parse(sc, path)
        val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
        import sqlContext.implicits._
        SaveUtil.saveAsOrc(rdd.toDF(), output)  // error
    }
}
```

I want to appoint the generic `T` to a case class:

```
case class X(uid: String, app: String, tag: String)

case class Y(uid: String, dvc: String, tag: String)
```

I'm a newbie for scala. The implicit conversion and covariant do not seem to work. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RDD.toDF()` exists thanks to an implicit conversion into a `DataFrameHolder`. This conversion is done by a [method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L46) with the following signature:

```
 implicit def rddToDataFrameHolder[A <: Product : TypeTag](rdd: RDD[A]): DataFrameHolder
```

So - for the conversion to work:

- `T` must be a subclass of `Product`, which is the super-class of all case classes (and Tuples, and more..).
- Caller must have an implicit `TypeTag` for the type `T` (to overcome type erasure)

So - you'd basically want to change the declaration of your trait as follows:

```
// won't work...
trait Extractor[T <: Product : TypeTag] { /* unchanged */ }
```

However, traits can't have types with context/view bounds, so this declaration won't work. Here you have two options:

1. Change your trait into a class (can be abstract) and add a `TypeTag`:

   ```
   abstract class Extractor[T <: Product : TypeTag] { /* unchanged */ }
   ```
2. Add an implicit argument to the `extract` method:

   ```
   trait Extractor[T <: Product] {

     def parse(sc: SparkContext, path: String): RDD[T]

     def extract(sc: SparkContext, path: String, output: String)(implicit evidence: TypeTag[T]): Unit = { /* unchanged */ }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Tzach Zohar very much! This problem has been solved perfectly!

Comment: Glad to know, please accept + upvote the answer so that future readers would find it easily

Answer (score 0):

```
object ExtractorX extends Extractor[X] {
    override parse(sc: SparkContext, path: String): RDD[X] = ...
}
```

or

```
val extractorX = new Extractor[X] {
    override parse(sc: SparkContext, path: String): RDD[X] = ...
}
```

Comment: I want to reuse the `extract` code block, but the `toDF()` method can be only be applied to RDD[case class]. So `SaveUtil.saveAsOrc(rdd.toDF(), output)` has an error in compiled time.